# How can I kill multiple processes at once in python?

Tags: python, pid, kill

I have a python script that is responsible for verifying the existence of a process with its respective name, I am using the pip module `pgrep`, the problem is that it does not allow me to kill the processes with the kill module of pip or with the of `os.kill` because there are several processes that I want to kill and these are saved in list, for example

`pid = [2222, 4444, 6666]`

How could you kill those processes at once? since the above modules don't give me results.

Comment: Write a `for` loop...

Comment: [os.kill(p,9) for p in pid].. this will kill one pid after another..

Comment: No @ArunKalirajaBaskaran - write a `for` loop - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: how would it look?

Comment: Oh okay, I'll post an answer. Just a sec...

Comment: Can you show us the error or warning you are getting with `os.kill`? AFAIK, the python process doesnt have permissions to kill these processes. 

Also could you try killing with sudo (in linux) or administrator (in windows) user

Answer (score 1):

You would loop over processes using a `for` loop.  Ideally you should send a `SIGTERM` before resorting to `SIGKILL`, because it can allow processes to exit more gracefully.

```
import time
import os
import signal

# send all the processes a SIGTERM
for p in pid:
    os.kill(p, signal.SIGTERM)

# give them a short time to do any cleanup
time.sleep(2)

# in case still exist - send them a SIGKILL to definitively remove them
# if they are already exited, just ignore the error and carry on
for p in pid:
    try:
        os.kill(p, signal.SIGKILL)
    except ProcessLookupError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work

```
processes = {'pro1', 'pro2', 'pro3'}
for proc in psutil.process_iter():  
    if proc.name() in processes:
       proc.kill()
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)